# How to display always just the first value from the same values in a result table of an SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a select query, which returns many same ordered values in one column.

Looks like this:

| Id | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | A |
| 4 | B |
| 5 | B |
| 6 | C |
| 7 | C |
| 8 | C |

But I like to display like this:

| Id | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 4 | B |
| 5 |  |
| 6 | C |
| 7 |  |
| 8 |  |

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Have a look at `ROW_NUMBER` and the `CASE` expression. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag` *window function*,

```
select t.id, 
    case when lag([type]) over(order by id)=[type] then '' else [type] end [Type]
from t
```